# API data rendering Issue in Child component in React

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 components.

- seatBooking.js => Parent
- seatPlans.js => Child
  I get some info through URL parameters and then,
  I call an API call in the parent component & pass some info to the child component to render the Seating Plan in the child component. Following are the info I sent to the Child component, Problem is sometimes it doesn't show the Seatplan.
- seatRows array

URL :
http://localhost:3000/#/seat-booking?movieid=3232&name=Mortal%20Kombat&theater=SkyxX&theaterId=90&movieDate=showtdates.date&showtimeId=2130&showTime=04:30%20PM
[image: Console]
My data Array when the fetch called in the Parent component

```
{
  "data": {
    "reservedSeats": {
      "reservedSeat": [
        {
          "seatTypeId": 536,
          "seatType": "ODC",
          "adultPrice": 350,
          "childPrice": 280,
          "childAvailable": true,
          "seatRows": [
            [
              {
                "id": "A1",
                "number": "A1",
                "orientation": "north",
                "selected": true
              },
              {
                "id": "A2",
                "number": "A2",
                "orientation": "north",
                "selected": false
              },
              {
                "id": "A3",
                "number": "A3",
                "orientation": "north",
                "selected": false
              },
              null,
              {
                "id": "A5",
                "number": "A5",
                "orientation": "north",
                "selected": false
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "nonReservedSeats": null
  },
  "success": true,
  "errorCode": null,
  "message": "Successful request!"
}
```

Parent Component

```
var movieData = []
var seatdata = []
const Mid = 0
var MoviedatatoPlan = []


export class seatBooking extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {seatSdata: [], MoviedatatoPlan: [], MovieSeatList: [],}
    this.onSeatData = this.onSeatData.bind(this);
  }

  onSeatData(seatSdata) {
    this.setState({seatSdata});
    seatdata = seatSdata
    console.log(seatdata)
  }

  

    componentDidMount() {
      let movieInfo = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search)
      console.log(movieInfo.movieid) 
      this.setState(movieInfo)
      console.log(movieInfo.name)          
      movieData = movieInfo 
      // MoviedatatoPlan = movieData

      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'client_token': 'ebd86470-7e90-4ece-9e89-1b6d4d2cbb61' }
      };
      fetch(
        // `http://595977570d12.ngrok.io/v1/seat?venueId=`+ movieData.venueId + `&movieId=`+ movieData.Mid + 
        //     `&showtimeId=` + movieData.showtimeId + `&movieDate=2021-08-05`
        `http://595977570d12.ngrok.io/v1/seat?venueId=90&movieId=3232&showtimeId=2130&movieDate=2021-08-05`
            , requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then((MovieSeatList) => {
            console.log(MovieSeatList.data.reservedSeats.reservedSeat)
            this.setState({ 
              MovieSeatList: MovieSeatList.data.reservedSeats.reservedSeat,
              dataLoaded: true,
             })
          }).catch(console.log);

    }
   

    render() {
const {MovieSeatList} = this.state;    

console.log(MovieSeatList)
MoviedatatoPlan = MovieSeatList
console.log(MoviedatatoPlan)
        return (
<div>
<PrimarySearchAppBar />
<div className="st_bt_top_header_wrapper float_left" style={{paddingTop:90}}>
  <div className="container container_seat">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div className="st_bt_top_back_btn st_bt_top_back_btn_seatl float_left"> <Link to="/movieBooking" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}> &nbsp;Back</Link>
        </div>
        </div>
      <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div className="st_bt_top_center_heading st_bt_top_center_heading_seat_book_page float_left">
          <h3>{movieData.name} - English</h3>
          <h4>{movieData.movieDate} , {movieData.showtimes} </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div className="st_bt_top_close_btn st_bt_top_close_btn2 float_left"> <a href="#/movies" style={{color:"#fff"}}><i className="fa fa-times" /></a>
        </div>
        <div className="st_seatlay_btn float_left"> 
        <Link to={'/bookingSummary?movieid=' + movieData.movieid + '&movieName=' + movieData.name + '&theater=' + movieData.theater + '&venueId=' + 
          movieData.theaterId + '&showtimeId=' + movieData.showtimeId + "&showTime=" + movieData.showTime +
          '&movieDate=' + movieData.movieDate + '&seats=' + seatdata}
        style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>Proceed</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<SeatPlan onData={this.onSeatData} dataParentToChild = {MovieSeatList}/>
</div>
        )
    }
}

export default seatBooking
```

Child Component

```
import React, {Component, useState} from 'react'
 
import SeatPicker from 'react-seat-picker';
import Screen from '../../images/content/screen.png';
import queryString from 'query-string';

var seats = [] 
var MovieSeatList = []
var data 
var seatPLan = []
export default class SeatPlan extends Component {

constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
    MovieSeatList: this.props.dataParentToChild
    
  }
  console.log(MovieSeatList)
}




  state = {
    loading: false
  }
 
  addSeatCallback = ({ row, number, id }, addCb) => {
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    }, async () => {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1500))
      console.log(`Added seat ${number}, row ${row}, id ${id}`)
      const newTooltip = `tooltip for id-${id} added by callback`
      addCb(row, number, id, newTooltip)
      this.setState({ loading: false })
    })
  }
 
  addSeatCallbackContinousCase = ({ row, number, id }, addCb, params, removeCb) => {
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    }, async () => {
      if (removeCb) {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 750))
        console.log(`Removed seat ${params.number}, row ${params.row}, id ${params.id}`)
        removeCb(params.row, params.number)
      }
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 750))
      console.log(`Added seat ${number}, row ${row}, id ${id}`)
      const newTooltip = `tooltip for id-${id} added by callback`
      addCb(row, number, id, newTooltip)
      // seats = {number}
      seats.push(number)
      this.setState({ loading: false })
      // console.log(seats)
      this.props.onData(seats)
    })
  }


 
  removeSeatCallback = ({ row, number, id }, removeCb) => {
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    }, async () => {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1500))
      console.log(`Removed seat ${number}, row ${row}, id ${id}`)
      // A value of null will reset the tooltip to the original while '' will hide the tooltip
      const newTooltip = ['A', 'B', 'C'].includes(row) ? null : ''
      removeCb(row, number, newTooltip)
      this.setState({ loading: false })
      seats.splice(seats.indexOf(number), 1);
      this.props.onData(seats)
    })
  }


 



  render() {

    const {MovieSeatList} = this.state;
    console.log(MovieSeatList)


    seatPLan = MovieSeatList
    console.log(seatPLan)
    
    const {loading} = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">{data}</div>
        <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style={{ marginTop: '10px', alignItems:'center' }}>
        <img src={Screen} width="450px"/>
        {seatPLan.map((seatingPlan) => {
          return(
            <SeatPicker
            addSeatCallback={this.addSeatCallbackContinousCase}
            removeSeatCallback={this.removeSeatCallback}
            rows={seatingPlan.seatRows}
            maxReservableSeats={5}
            // alpha
            // visible
            selectedByDefault
            loading={loading}
            tooltipProps={{ multiline: true }}
            continuous
          />
          );
        })}
        </div>
        <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"></div>
      </div>
    )
  } 
}
```

Comment: do you have a working example like code sandbox ?

Comment: Try this https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-feynman-wcfo4?file=/src/seatPlan.js
it gets some errors but the code is OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be the API call on the parent is not asynchronous and thus the child could have no data from parent until the parent completes the API call

```js
getSeats = async() =>
{
  try
  {
    await fetch("")
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

```js
import { Component } from "react";
// class based component (Older React)

class Parent extends Component{

  componentDidMount()
  {
    this.getSeats()
  }

  getSeats = async() =>
  {
    try {
      await fetch("")
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error", error)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share some example pass data between parent & child. have I done something wrong in passing data between components?

Comment: You mentioned in your question that sometimes you don't receive the props, so it means that the props are passed correctly. The problem is with the API call on the parent. I will update my answer with code to make API call asynchronously

Comment: how to apply this solution to the project?

Comment: create this function inside your parent component, and call it inside the componentDidMount, that should do the trick, you can also set a state for loading until the API call is complete for better user experience

Comment: can you please share an example I'm bit new to React

Comment: I think the problem is in passing data to child. because when I put a console.log I see the API call is being made correctly. (updated the question)